# Confusion on return type deduction with unpacking references

Tags: c++, reference, type-deduction

The following code

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

decltype(auto) memrefs(Point &p)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(p.x), std::ref(p.y));
}

int main()
{
    Point p;
    auto& [x, y] = memrefs(p);
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

does not compile. Reported by GCC 8.1.0:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::tuple<int&, int&>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::tuple<int&, int&>'

However, it will compile if I change

`auto& [x, y] = memrefs(p);`

to

`auto [x, y] = memrefs(p)`

My question is why? Aren't `x` and `y` references?

Comment: `decltype(auto) memrefs(Point &p)` returns a temporary value ie an rvalue.  rvalues can only be bound the `const &`, or as in your 2nd case copied.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It kind of makes sense to me now. I just couldn't get my head around the fact that you have to use `auto& x = getref();` when a single reference is returned, but not when multiple references are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
decltype(auto) memrefs(Point &p);
```

is

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, int&> memrefs(Point &p);
```

In [structured_binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding),
`auto&` in `auto& [x, y]` applies to the *"tuple"*, not to `x`, `y`.

and you cannot have

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, int&>& tup = memrefs(p);
```

but you can have

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, int&> tup = memrefs(p);
```

then `x`, `y` refers to the appropriate part of the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
return std::make_tuple(std::ref(p.x), std::ref(p.y));
```

is constructing a temporary local variable of type `std::tuple<int&, int&>` and returns it as a rvalue. In this case, being a temporary variable, it can be acquired with a *const reference* (`const std::tuple<int&, int&>&`) or it can be copied into a new tuple (`std::tuple<int&, int&>`). In your case you are trying to acquire a non const reference (`std::tuple <int&, int&>&`) to a temporary object and this is not allowed.

How you pointed out, the solution is to copy the value returned by `memrefs` in a new value or to acquire it using a const reference.

Comment: i would agree with you, but https://pastebin.com/8p6JY7fb

Comment: it prints out std::tuple<int&, int&> const&

Comment: Online compiler as [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78343ea1bf371acc) or [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n61YjKhn1) is more appropriate than pastebin

Comment: Indeed, [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) handles `std::reference_wrapper` to use reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 so in short, i m right with `int&`?

Comment: Yes, you are right with `int&`